# Writing text based on words in text files

Tags: python, file, sorting, text

I am trying to split text into separate files by political party based on whether the name that precedes a block of text appears in a text file of Democrat last names or a text file of Republican last names. After I fix the text files for extra characters and set them up correctly, this is the code that hasn't been working:

```
with open("RepublicanList.txt") as f:
    frepnames = list(f)

with open("DemocratList.txt") as f:
    fdemnames = list(f)

with open ("TextFile.txt") as file:
    lines = file.read()
lines = lines.split(" ")

republican = ""
democrat = ""

for index, word in enumerate(lines):
    if(republican == "yeah"):
        for index2, word2 in enumerate(fdemnames):
            if(word == word2): 
                republican = ""
        if(republican == "yeah"):
            frepwrite.write(word + " ")
    else:
        for index3, word3 in enumerate(frepnames):
            if(word == word3):
                republican = "yeah"
                frepwrite.write("\n\n")
                frepwrite.write("Ms. " + word + " ")

frepwrite.close()
fdemwrite.close()
```

For whatever reason, no text at all ever gets written into the Republican text file. I know there are matches in the text (that's how I made the lists in the first place) but it just never picks anything up. My goal was to do this code once for the Republicans to sort them, and then switch the code around to then allow it to write into the Democrat file.

The text file of names looks something like "NAME NAME2 NAME3 NAME4" for both files. Basically I want to check whether or not a word matches a Republican last name in the republican last name text file, and then if it does, write all of the text afterwards until it reaches a Democrat last name with Democrat speech text (obviously I don't want that included in the republican text file).

Appreciate the help in advance and let me know if I can help clarify anything!

Comment: It is not clear what `frepwrite` is.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using  `with open(filename) as file:`
the file will be automatically closed if you exit the scope.

```py
>>> with open('workfile') as f:
...     read_data = f.read()

>>> # We can check that the file has been automatically closed.
>>> f.closed
True
```

This is borrowed from [Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files)

The second mistake is that if you use `open(filename)`
the file will just be opened in readmode. So you have to explicit tell python to open it in read mode like this `open(filename, "w")`.

[There are multiple parameters like "w"](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open)

Comment: Doesn't it not matter if the files are closed because I turned the files into lists/strings that can still be interacted with? That's what the frepnames, fdemnames and lines variables are.

Comment: You just copied the content of the textfile in a list and not the filepointer.
So every operation is stored in that list and won't be transfered to the file.
You can check this by using `type(frepnames)` -> list and `type(frepnames[0])` -> string. These are just normal types and aren't a file(pointer)